# Pandas: Used on priority of entries eliminate duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dateframe like this:

```
     FRUITS     COLOURS  
0     apple      red  
1     berry      black         
2     apple      green     
3     grapes     green    
4     apple      black          
5     grapes     red  
6     tomato     black
7     tomato     green
```

keeping in mind the priority order of COLOURS red > green > black, i want to eliminate all the duplicate entries in FRUITS

Desired output should be:

```
     FRUITS    COLOURS  
0     apple     red    
1     berry     black         
2     grapes    red  
3     tomato    green
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the order by setting `COLOUR` to an ordered categorical, then sorting, and dropping the duplicate `FRUITS`:

```
df['COLOURS'] = pd.Categorical(df['COLOURS'], categories=['red','green','black'],ordered=True)

df.sort_values('COLOURS').drop_duplicates('FRUITS').sort_index()

   FRUITS COLOURS
0   apple     red
1   berry   black
5  grapes     red
7  tomato   green
```